# How do I use input() to get the name of a new composer project from the user?

Tags: vimscript, functions

I often start new projects in the same way. I guess it exists a way to be fast a starting a project.

For example: I am trying to start new composer project with the following function. I perfectly see the string `'New Project name: '`.

But when I press enter, my cursor just goes on top of current file.

```
function! CreateProject()
    let new_name = input('New Project name: ')
    exec '!composer create-project foo/bar ' + l:new_name + ' 1.0.0'
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concatenating string, you should use `.` instead of `+`.

I don't have composer installed, so instead of calling composer, I simply called the unix `echo` function like so :

```
exec '!echo ' . l:new_name . ' 1.0.0'
```

And it prints the entered name with the `1.0.0` after.

Ref :

- http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html
- [`:h expr-.`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-.)

Comment: You have no composer, but you solved my problem. It is running!!!